# Add number of repetitions in a separate column based on values in multiple columns

Tags: text-processing, awk

I am trying to add the number of occurance in the last column of a pipe delimited file based on column 1, 2 and 3.

I have tried `awk '{ print $0 "|" ++count[$1,$2,$3] }'`

But it is producing just number 1 in the last column in all the rows adding an additional pipe as below

```
123|456365|PASS|566563|Apple||1
123|456365|PASS|566563|Apple||1
123|456365|FAIL|34322|Apple1||1
123|456365|FAIL|35322|Apple2||1
```

It would be very helpful if someone can help me out to get it working to get the expected output below.

**Input file**

```
123|456365|PASS|566563|Apple
123|456365|FAIL|34322|Apple1
123|456365|FAIL|35322|Apple2
123|456335|PASS|56655|Apple34
123|456335|FAIL|34325|Apple53
123|34343|PASS|35323|Apple1
123|34343|PASS|34342|Apple13
123|34343|PASS|343442|Apple13
```

**Expected output**

```
123|456365|PASS|566563|Apple|1
123|456365|FAIL|34322|Apple1|1
123|456365|FAIL|35322|Apple2|2
123|456335|PASS|56655|Apple34|1
123|456335|FAIL|34325|Apple53|1
123|34343|PASS|35323|Apple1|1
123|34343|PASS|34342|Apple13|2
123|34343|PASS|343442|Apple13|3
```

Comment: Not really but I can sort it if needed.

Comment: no needed sort, it's fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You needed to tell awk what is the field seperator:

```
awk -F'|' -v OFS='|' '{ print $0, ++count[$1,$2,$3] }' infile
```

with `-F` we defined input field seperator and with `-v OFS` defined output field seperator; instead we could use `BEGIN{ FS=OFS="|" }` for both like:

```
awk 'BEGIN{ FS=OFS="|" } { print $0, ++count[$1,$2,$3] }' infile
```

Answer (score 1):

**Using Raku (formerly known as Perl_6)**

```perl
raku -ne ' state %seen; print($_, "|"); for $_.split("|").[0..2].join() { (++%seen{$_}).put };'
```

OR

```perl
raku -ne ' state %seen; print($_, "|"); ( ++%seen{$_} ).put for .split("|").[0..2].join;'
```

Sample Input:

```
123|456365|PASS|566563|Apple
123|456365|FAIL|34322|Apple1
123|456365|FAIL|35322|Apple2
123|456335|PASS|56655|Apple34
123|456335|FAIL|34325|Apple53
123|34343|PASS|35323|Apple1
123|34343|PASS|34342|Apple13
123|34343|PASS|343442|Apple13
```

Sample Output:

```
123|456365|PASS|566563|Apple|1
123|456365|FAIL|34322|Apple1|1
123|456365|FAIL|35322|Apple2|2
123|456335|PASS|56655|Apple34|1
123|456335|FAIL|34325|Apple53|1
123|34343|PASS|35323|Apple1|1
123|34343|PASS|34342|Apple13|2
123|34343|PASS|343442|Apple13|3
```

Above are solutions coded in Raku, a member of the Perl-family of programming languages. Briefly, `raku` is run at the command line with the `-ne` (line-wise, non-autoprinting) flags. A hash `%seen` is `state`-d at the beginning of the one-liner. This allows `%seen` to be initialized exactly once. In the second statement, the original line followed by a `|` is `print`-ed (without a newline). Then in the third statement the first three columns are `split` on `|` and re-`join`-ed, and each value obtained is `++%seen{$_}` used to increment the `%seen` hash based on its unique string value. The incremented value is `put` to complete the solution.

https://raku.org